# Error: Unable to publish yor file in pentaho?

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio

I am new to pentaho. I am using Pentaho Report Desiner ce-5.3.0 on Windows 7 32 bit.

When I try to publish report then login window popup then filling all fields and click on ok, it gives error.

> Unable to publish your file
>
> please try again or contact to your system administrator for assistance.

Then I have following message in error window.

```
Internal error occure

 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.util.PublishException: The File exists and override has not been specified.
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.UpdateReservedCharsTask.run(UpdateReservedCharsTask.java:90)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:870)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:667)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:638)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.PublishToServerTask.showErrorMessage(PublishToServerTask.java:170)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.PublishToServerTask.run(PublishToServerTask.java:105)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.util.PublishException: The File exists and override has not been specified.
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.UpdateReservedCharsTask.run(UpdateReservedCharsTask.java:84)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Report designer and bi server should be same. try that and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

The error says the file already exists. You must either delete the file beforehand or check the "overwrite" checkbox.